# Reporting percentage of an element visible in the viewport - function reporting incorrect values with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, scroll

I have a section on my site where the visitor scrolls down past 4 panels of varying height, but equal widths. I want to change the background based on whichever element occupies most screen space.

In the past I used a function that simply set the background to a colour based on when an element is 100% visible in the viewport. However when the viewport height is smaller than the element height, this obviously breaks. So now I have resorted to setting the background based on the dominant panel rather than the one that is 100% visible.

My function is as follows:

```
const isScrolledIntoViewPerc = el => {
  let elemTop = el.offsetTop;
  let elemHeight = el.offsetHeight;
  let elemBottom = elemTop + elemHeight;
  let screenTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  let screenBottom = screenTop + window.innerHeight;
  let result = 0;

  if (elemTop > screenTop) {
    // scrolled off bottom of screen
    if (elemBottom < screenBottom) {
      // fully
      result = 100;
    } else if (elemTop < screenBottom) {
      // partially
      result = ((screenBottom - elemTop) / elemHeight) * 100;
    }
  } else if (elemBottom > screenTop) {
    // scrolled off top of screen
    result = ((elemBottom - screenTop) / elemHeight) * 100;
  }

  return +result.toFixed(2);
}
```

This reports percentage correctly, as verified in [this pen I made](https://codepen.io/adstr123/pen/oKgrpW).

However in the context of my application, it does not report correctly. The percentages as viewed in the console for each of the elements come too early. E.g. when panel 1/4 is half on the screen it is reported as 100%. And as you scroll further down, when you reach around panel 3, panel 4 is already reported as 100% visible! I don't understand why this is.

Here is the context (React components). The function above is imported and named as above.

A parent component `Parent.js` using React hooks, that updates state from children by passing a function as props:

```
const [activeSlide, updateActiveSlide] = useState('some-title')

const getVisibilityFromChild = (childId, childVisibility) => {
  console.log(`${childId} with visibility ${childVisibility}`)
  // logic to update background based on largest number
}

return (
  <Content
    title="Title"
    passVisibilityUpwards={getVisibilityFromChild}
  >
)
```

A container component that wraps all 4 panels, `Content.js` calls the function passed as a prop as such:

```
// fires on scroll, for each of the 4 panels
checkVisibleOnScroll = () => {
  this.props.passVisibilityUpwards(
    slugify(this.props.title),
    isScrolledIntoViewPerc(this.panelRef.current)
  )
}
```

Let me know if I need to add any more details.

Comment: Have you considered that `this.panelRef.current` used at `checkVisibleOnScroll` might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I have considered it but I didn't consider it particularly likely, coupled with the fact I'm not sure how to debug it has stopped me from investigating that any further to be honest. Any tips?

Comment: I was thinking about: give the same elements that have these refs an id, then, instead of passing the node you get via the ref to your function, pass the node via `getElementById()`

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I never thought of this because I avoid accessing the DOM directly in React due to best practise. I tried it, and unfortunately the same behaviour is observed. So I think we can rule out issues with the refs

Comment: Thanks for tryin that, one thing eliminated, for me to make this easier, and you not to waste more time with more suggestions, can you provide a minimal working React implementation for this functionality accross your components through [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21)?